# lightbox doesn't work on new content generated after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having problems with my lightbox after ajax call

At the moment it is like this

```
$(".trackz").click(function () {
    $(".contentmusic").remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: "data/loadContent.php?clickedcontent=" + $(this).attr("id"),
        success: function (html) {
            if (html) {
                $("#lightbox-panel").append(html);
                $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But when i load newcontent with this ajax call

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

         var myStylesLocation = "css/demo.css";

         $.ajax({
             url: "data/loadMoreMusic.php?lastMusic=" + $(".trackz:last").attr("id"),
             success: function (html) {
                 if (html) {
                     $("#trackz").append(html);
                     $('.fdw-background').hover(
                         function () {
                             $(this).animate({
                                 opacity: '1'
                             });
                         },
                         function () {
                             $(this).animate({
                                 opacity: '0'
                             });
                         }
                     );
                 } else {
                     $('div#loadMoreMusic').replaceWith("<center>Finished loading Music</center>");
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

My lightbox doesn't work anymore on my new content generated by the 2nd ajax call. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Does `.trackz` exist inside the content you're updating? If so, you need to use [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (probably) trying to trigger on an element that doesn't exist yet when the DOM is loaded.

Use this:

```
//another notation because we want to trigger on a DOM manipulation
$('.someClass').on("click", "#someId", function(event){
     //do something
});
```

Where `.someClass` is a class that already exists when the DOM is loaded, and
where `#someId` is an id you want to click on, but didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you replace:

```
$(".trackz").click(function () {
```

With

```
$(".trackz").on('click', function () {
```

When you add dynamic content to your DOM, you can't utilize their event handling. The `on()` method allows you access to event handlers on an element regardless of whether the DOM is changed.

You should also be using the new functionality of `ajax()`. Success functionality should be placed in `done()` (method chained on the same jQuery object).

Comment: nothing happens when i replace $(".trackz").click(function () { with $(".trackz").on('click', function () { it stays the same my lightbox only work on content generated before the ajax call

Comment: If you put `alert('hello')` after `$(".contentmusic").remove();` does it show an alert when you click on `.trackz` after the new content is generated?

Comment: what do you mean with this You should also be using the new functionality of ajax(). Success functionality should be placed in done() (method chained on the same jQuery object). ?

Comment: If you change `$(".trackz").click(function () {` to `$(".trackz").on('click', function () { alert("Hello");` what happens when you click on the tracks button? Still nothing?

Comment: Can you try making a jsFiddle?